# How do I turn IDENTITY_INSERT ON when adding information from the web to the database

Tags: sql, asp.net, web-applications, user-registration

I am doing registration form, to register users. I can add users from the query :

```
Set IDENTITY_INSERT Table_1 ON

insert into Table_1(RegisterId, UserName, Email,Password)
values(2, 'RRE', 'besa@live.com', '1234f456')
```

BUT when I try to register from the web on the registration form it says :

> Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Table_1'
>   when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.

```
public ActionResult Register() { return View(); } 
public ActionResult Register(RegisterViewModel model) 
{ if(ModelState.IsValid) 
  { RegisterService service = new RegisterService(); 
    service.SaveRegisterDetailts(model); 
    ViewBag.SaveDetails = "Register Details Saved"; 
    return View(); 
   } 
   else { return View(model); } 
}
```

How can  fix this ?

Thank you

Comment: How do you run those both commands? From asp.net code or from procedure ?

Comment: why do you need to use the `IDENTITY_INSERT` feature on first place?

Comment: Set whichever field uniquely identifies the row to be IDENTITY in the database and forget about modifying tables from a front end.

Comment: The first one I RUN from SQL server and it works.When I run from front end. It shows that Message

Comment: @BesaNeziri Can you input that code from front end?

Comment: public ActionResult Register()
        {
            return View();
        }
public ActionResult Register(RegisterViewModel model)
        {
            if(ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                RegisterService service = new RegisterService();
                service.SaveRegisterDetailts(model);
                ViewBag.SaveDetails = "Register Details Saved";
                return View();
            }
            else
            {
                return View(model);
            }
        }

Comment: @BesaNeziri Based on your code I can't find the problem. Can you include a code with `Set IDENTITY_INSERT Table_1 ON` line?

Comment: The code above works from the sql server.From the web it does not.When I run the app on chrome I see the form and I try to register than the form stops at : dataContext.SaveChanges();
and it says :Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Table_1' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.